# R plot response average and count per categories

Tags: r, plot

I have a classification task to do, and many categorical features.

I wish to plot all my categorical variables in order to have the average response (success ratio) per category, and counts per category.

Is there a library to do this?

For example, here is what I am doing right now:

```
df = structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
"1"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), response = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "t"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "response"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")


barplotClassSuccessRatio <- function(var_name, x,y)
{
    tab = table(x, y)
    barplot(cbind(tab, tab[,2]/(tab[,1]+tab[,2]))[,3], main=paste0("Success ratio per ",var_name), ylim=c(0,1))
}

barplotClassSamplesCount <- function(var_name, x,y)
{
    tab = table(x)
    barplot(tab, main=paste0("Samples count per ",var_name))
}

# plot for var1
old.par <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
barplotClassSuccessRatio("var1", df$var1, df$response)
barplotClassSamplesCount("var1", df$var1)
par(old.par)
```

[image]

```
# the plot for var2
old.par <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
barplotClassSuccessRatio("var2", df$var2, df$response)
barplotClassSamplesCount("var2", df$var2)
par(old.par)
```

Is there a R package / library that can help me quickly visualize this type of information for all categorical variables?

Comment: Is it essential that `var1` and `var2` remain `factor`?

Comment: @beginneR No they do not need to remain factors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just use a `for` loop and create all the plots?

```
df[1:2] <- apply(df[1:2], 2, as.numeric)    #convert the `var*` columns to numeric

par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

for(i in 1:2){
  barplot(table(df[df$response == "t",i])/sum(table(df[df$response == "t",i])),
          main = paste("Success count per var", i, sep=""))
  barplot(table(df[,i]), main = paste("Samples count per var", i, sep=""))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a combination of `reshape2` , `plyr` and `ggplot2`. Btw, note that some of this could be done significantly easier with some of the base stats that come with `geom_bar` but this should be a more general solution that you can use in other scenarios (or if you're presenting just a trivial example here).

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
#flatten out our data.frame, so that each row contains 1 variable/value/
mdf<-melt(df,id.vars=c("response"))
#summarize the stats
mdf<-ddply(mdf, .(variable, value), summarize, 
           success_ratio=mean(response=="t"),
           sample_counts=length(response))
#flatten the summarized version of the data.frame
mdf<-melt(mdf, id.vars=c("variable","value"), 
          variable.name="stat", 
          value.name="result")

#graph it out
ggplot(mdf, aes(x=value, y=result))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(stat~variable , scales="free_y")
```

[image]